# Haskell, getting value from bindings

Tags: haskell, monads

Here is an example from haskell tutorial:

```
type Bindings = Map.Map String Int

isCountCorrect :: Bindings -> Bool
isCountCorrect bindings = runReader calc_isCountCorrect bindings

calc_isCountCorrect :: Reader Bindings Bool
calc_isCountCorrect = do
    count <- asks (lookupVar "count")
    bindings <- ask
    return (count == (Map.size bindings))

lookupVar :: String -> Bindings -> Int
lookupVar name bindings = fromJust (Map.lookup name bindings)

sampleBindings = Map.fromList [("count", 4), ("1", 1), ("b", 2)]

main = do
    putStr $ "Count is correct for bindings " ++ (show  sampleBindings) ++ ": "
    putStrLn $ show (isCountCorrect sampleBindings)
```

I created function to get value for "2". I have no idea how to make it generic for arbitrary String.  Could you help me ?

```
get_valueM :: Reader Bindings Int
get_valueM = asks (lookupVar "b") >>= (\value -> ask >>= (\_ -> return value))

get_value :: Bindings -> Int
get_value bindings = runReader get_valueM bindings
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question completely. Why don't you add a parameter for `"b"` ?

```
get_valueM :: String -> Reader Bindings Int
get_valueM x = asks (lookupVar "b") >>= (\value -> ask >>= (\_ -> return value))
```

By the way, what is the last `ask` for? You don't use its result and it has no side effects, so it looks as it can be removed.

```
get_valueM :: String -> Reader Bindings Int
get_valueM x = asks (lookupVar "b") >>= (\value -> return value)
```

which can be simplified to

```
get_valueM :: String -> Reader Bindings Int
get_valueM x = asks (lookupVar "b") >>= return
```

which can be simplified to

```
get_valueM :: String -> Reader Bindings Int
get_valueM x = asks (lookupVar "b")
```

Finally, let me add that I consider these partial functions dangerous. `lookupVar` shouldn't crash when a binding is not found. Still, these can be convenient when toying around.

Comment: Additionally, I used ask because >>= passes enviroment to two subcomputations. So I can't put this function to get this argument (enviroment)